# Convert Open XML Excel files to HTML

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, openxml

I'm developing printing solution for MS Office 2007. Office automation is not right for me, because it requires Office to be installed. [Open XML Document Viewer](http://openxmlviewer.codeplex.com/) is solution for converting Word files (.docx) to HTML format by XSLT transform, but it works only for .docx. Can the same technology be used for Excel spreadsheets files?

Comment: Are we talking the compress open standard (.xlsx) or the SpreadsheetML (.xml) formats?

Comment: SpreadsheetML of course. But (.xlsx) is only packaged SpreadsheetML xml files with resources. I need to generate html from xml files with extraxting and linking resources.

Comment: @necrostaz : I don't believe XLSX is just re-packaged SpreadsheetML, I think they are quite different from my memory of looking at them.

Comment: Okay, there are several versions of SpreadsheetML, i mean Open XML SpreadsheetML specified by ECMA and used in Office 2007 and later. It specifies files, resources, relations etc. and all of that packaged in xlsx.

Comment: necrostaz is right. an XSLX is a packaged version of SpreadsheetML (and any other MLs in the package, most commonly DrawingML) in the Open Document Format.

Comment: @necrostaz: just wanted to check in with you to see if the answer below answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this article [XSL transformation of SpreadsheetML to HTML](http://openxmldeveloper.org/articles/875.aspx) as a starting point to develop your own transform. You can also look at the open source XSLTs in [OpenXML/ODF Translator Add-ins for Office](http://odf-converter.sourceforge.net/) to get some ideas on things you may need to account for in any conversion outside of OOXML. The one thing to keep in mind is that SpreadsheetML is more similiar to PresentationML than it is to WordprocessingML in file structure inside the package (i.e. for every sheet, there is a seperate file).

If your doing this from .NET, I'd do this from LINQ instead of XSLT. I've done transforms from DrawingML into SVG and Linq makes it easy (in terms of similiar functionality to XSLT, staying within .NET, etc.)

Comment: thanks for your response! I've already work on open office and openxml-odf translators code, also i was read XSL transformation of SpreadsheetML to HTML article but i suppose it no more effective way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at Excel 97-03 (xls) or Excel 2007 (xlsx) files then I'd recommend [FlexCel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp#features). I've used it, is very good and honestly quite cheap compared to it's competition.

Note that it doesn't fully support all formatting present in Excel 2007 yet I don't think. But it does have built in functionality to export to HTML.

Comment: Thanks, but proprietary or shareware libs are not suitable for me :(

Comment: You might want to put that in the original question then as its not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a SpreadsheetML parser. The [schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066(office.10).aspx) is available online from Microsoft.

I wrote one a while back that covered data, structure and basic formatting to throw it throw a library and re-save it as an XLS file. Wasn't too difficult.

Comment: This schema for 2002 Office, but i need OpenXml SpreadsheetML which schema is difficult, therefore i need to find any existing solutions :(

Comment: OpenXml and SpreadsheetML aren't the same thing... SpreadsheetML specfically refers to the XML format present in Office 2003 and later. Not XLSX files. Don't combine OpenXml and SpreadsheetML in the same sentence if referring to just a single thing.

Comment: xslx = Excel Extensions to the Office Open XML SpreadsheetML 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd922181.aspx
and anywhere in open xml community used SpreadsheetMl term, but initially it defined for Office 2003.
For Office 2003 it has schema urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet, for XLSX - http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main