# convert xml to xls

Tags: xml, excel, vba, xls

I'm looking for ideas on how to implement a way to get web based XML data into a spreadsheet. The ideal solution would update the spreadsheet every time it's opened with little or no user interaction (.i.e, I'd prefer to not have to tell people to run a macro).

however, my first thought (and probably what I'll end up going with) is a Perl script that downloads the XML, parses it, and spits out a spreadsheet - this won't update the spreadsheet and I'll have to generate the document on some type of schedule (yes, i prefer complete automation and coding myself out of jobs :) ). what i (think i) want is odbc for XML that would accept a URI, that would probably be ideal. this way, maybe i could map the XPath to columns and the spreadsheet would update automagically every time it was opened. or, maybe there's a way in VBA to get a URI and parse XML and have it run when the workbook is opened?

Comment: Why not upgrade to the XSLX format and then you can use XSL to map your XML across? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372731/convert-open-xml-excel-files-to-html

Comment: i didn't understand the link as far as mapping an xml xpath.... i'm reading elsewhere. i'm also hoping it's backward compatible (as i know one of my clients uses 2003 and i don't know what everyone else is using).

Comment: i see what you're getting at now... http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-xml-data-HP010206405.aspx

i wonder if this is a part of the xlsx format and if this would still work on office 2000/2003 etc? this would be awesome if i could use those versions with the compatibility pack and make this work..?

Comment: If all you need to do is to create a spreadsheet file which can be opened by Excel, then you don't really need to think along the lines of automating Excel at all - you can simply create the file. XSLX is XML (compressed), and given that your source is XML, XSL seems a natural mapping technology.

Comment: and, when the web site gets updated, i don't see the updates in excel. at this point, i've got 20 lines of perl (plus Excel::Writer::XLSX formatting stuff) to make this happen. i was asking for the *dynamic* way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the XML file using DOM, then spit out the relevant values onto your sheet. Here's a trivial working example to get you started:

```
Dim d As DOMDocument
Dim n As IXMLDOMNode
Dim s As String

Set d = New DOMDocument
d.async = False 
d.Load "http://www.democracynow.org/podcast-video.xml" ' or "C:\myfile.xml"

Set n = d.SelectSingleNode("//channel/description")
s = n.Text
Range("A1") = s
```

This early binding requires a reference set as follows:
Tools > References... > Microsoft XML

Note that `d.async = False` forces the load to complete before proceeding further; this is especially important when loading remote files.

You want to

> update the spreadsheet every time it's opened with little or no user interaction (ie, i'd prefer to not have to tell people to run a macro)."

Then put the macro in the `Workbook_Open` event! That's what it's there for.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the xml file? is this location fix?

If yes, you can create a dataconnection in Excel to this xml file.

Then setup the xml connection to refresh when the excel file opens.

Comment: it's a remote file - on the web.

Comment: So it should works. Simply add a connection that points to this Xml file. That will allow to create a table with this data.