# Convert Excel-XML to XLS

Tags: oracle, plsql

My task is to convert Excel .xls file to Excel-XML format file([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats)). Edit cell values and write it back to .xls.

Convert from xls to xml maybe can't be done automatically. Editing file is easy with XMLTABLE and XMLQUERY in Oracle. When I save XML content with XLS extension it give me Error:

> The file you are trying to open MyFile.xls is in a different format than
>   specified by the file extension. Verify the file is not corrupted and
>   is from trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open
>   the file now?

When I select "Yes" option file is opening and everything work fine. I want to avoid this Error/Warning message.

There is some way to convert Excel-XML file to other Excel's format and not xml? I know the problem is that I change only file extension without change format, but maybe there is solution hint excel to open file without Warning or convert to real xls.

Notes:
Error/Warning can be see displayed edit file content. Steps are: Open Excel file, Save as *Excel XML*(file is save with *.xml* extension), Close file, Rename file extension to *.xls*, Open file with Excel and Error is displayed.

Comment: Why would you even consider Oracle, or any other database, for his task. Nothing is sourced from a database nor anything output to a database; converting Excel formats is not a task a DBMS is suited for. Your last paragraph begins solving your problem but instead of storing as .XML store it as XLS ,also [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203403/convert-xml-to-xls). BTW renaming a file from .xml to .xls caused the error. Changing the file extensiona file does not change it's internal structure. That what the error is: Internal structure does not match extension.

Comment: Yes, I know the reason for the error. It's just a description of what I tried. There is only Oracle database (no java ascepted). Input file is xls. We save this file as Excel XML (this xls file is a template and this conversion is once) and store it in a database in xmltype. With code we fill in the some values ​​in the file and the result is this xml. But final document have to send like xls. I try to do this automatically without the need for manual opening file and saving as xls (or run macros).